# Calculating Metropolis-Hastings algorithm correction term

Tags: normal-distribution, metropolis-hastings, scipy

I am teaching myself about different samplers and currently going through a course. They write up an example of the Metropolis algorithm (MA), which I am pretty sure I understand. They next propose the reader convert the MA into the Metropolis-Hastings Algorithm (MHA). However, I am having trouble calculating the correction term. I have understood it as the following:

$(_{}|_{})/(_{}|_{})$.

Such that $(_{}|_{})$ is the probability density of drawing $_{}$ from a normal distribution centered around $_{}$ and vice versa. To calculate this, I performed the following steps:

```
from scipy.stats import norm
numerator = norm.pdf(current, loc = proposed, scale= 0.5)
denominator = norm.pdf(proposed, loc = current, scale= 0.5)
correction_term = numerator/denominator
```

However, I must not be using norm.pdf correctly because numerator is the same as denominator.

I am using the MA algorithm to find possible lambda parameters for a Poisson distribution.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.special import gamma, factorial
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt 
from scipy.stats import norm

# Prior alpha = 7, beta = 1
# Start with a value of lambda given by 8.0 and compute the prior probability density of observing this value

def prior_prob_density(lam, alpha, beta):
     return(beta**(alpha) * lam**(alpha - 1) * np.exp(-beta*lam) / gamma(alpha))

def likelihood_density(data, lam):
    return(lam**(data) * np.exp(-lam)/ factorial(data))

# Starting value of lambda
lambda_current = 8.0
# Prior parameters alpha and beta
alpha = 7.0
beta = 1.0
# Observed data of 9 events 
data_val = 9

lambda_array = np.zeros(1000)
for i in range(1000):
    
    # Current value 
    prior = prior_prob_density(lam=lambda_current, alpha=alpha, beta=beta)
    likelihood = likelihood_density(data=data_val, lam=lambda_current)
    posterior_current = likelihood * prior 
    
    # Proposed value
    lambda_proposed = np.random.normal(lambda_current, scale=0.5) # scale is our tuning parameter
    prior = prior_prob_density(lam=lambda_proposed, alpha=alpha, beta=beta)
    likelihood = likelihood_density(data=data_val, lam=lambda_proposed)
    posterior_proposed = likelihood * prior
    
    # correction term
    num = norm.pdf(lambda_current, loc = lambda_proposed, scale= 0.5)
    denom = norm.pdf(lambda_proposed, loc = lambda_current, scale= 0.5)
    # Compute the probability of move
    ratio = posterior_proposed * num / (posterior_current * denom)
    p_move = min(ratio, 1)
    random_draw = np.random.uniform(0,1)
    if (random_draw < p_move):
        lambda_current = lambda_proposed
        
    # Store the current value
    lambda_array[i] = lambda_current
```

Comment: The distinction between Metropolis and Metropolis-Hastings algorithms is rather unusual. In your code, proposed values of lambda that are negative should be rejected, but I do not see a provision for that case.

Answer (score 1):

You don't say explicitly what your proposal distribution is, but it looks like it's a random walk $N(0,0.5)$ from the current parameter value.  For this proposal distribution, the density for the forward and return steps are the same, and the correction term disappears -- this is "random-walk Metropolis" sampling.  The point of the Metropolis-Hastings correction is to allow proposal distributions that *aren't* symmetric in this way.

Comment: I was under the impression that would not matter. I have updated the question to include how I am calculating Metropolis-Hastings.

Comment: I think I answered my own question? It should be 1 since we are drawing mu from normal distributions. When does the correction term not equal 1? When the "num" and "denom" are not from a normal distribution? Is it that obvious?

Comment: It's nothing about Normal distributions specifically; it's that the forward and backwards densities are the same, which would be true for any symmetric proposal distribution